# AWS CloudFormation - AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer - SecurityGroups

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a possibility in CFN templates to add some specific Security Groups to ALB depending on the parameter?

I have a situation where two security groups are adding to the ALB:

```
ALB
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    ...
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref 'SecurityGroup1'
      - !Ref 'SecurityGroup2'
```

Now there is a `SecurityGroup3` that I would like to eventually add only if some parameter has a specific value. Let's say if parameter `add_sg3` equals `yes` then the third SG is added to ALB. I always use `"!If` in similar situations but there are more than 2 SGs. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using a [Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) and the [`AWS::NoValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue) pseudo-parameter. Follow below a complete example:

```yaml
Parameters:
    Environment:
        Type: String
        Default: dev
        AllowedValues: ["dev", "prod"]
    VpcId:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    Subnet1:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
    Subnet2:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'

Conditions:
    MyTest: !Equals ["dev", !Ref Environment]

Resources:
    ALB:
        Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
        Properties:
            SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecurityGroup1
            - !If [ MyTest, !Ref SecurityGroup2, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue' ]
            Subnets:
            - !Ref Subnet1
            - !Ref Subnet2

    SecurityGroup1:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
        Properties:
            GroupDescription: 'Group 1'
            VpcId: !Ref VpcId

    SecurityGroup2:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
        Properties:
            GroupDescription: 'Group 2'
            VpcId: !Ref VpcId
```

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. I didn't have a chance to test it before. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!